# I'm trying to fix my while loop for a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

what I'm trying to do with my code is that I want the player to have 4 chances to guess the correct answer out of 8 words to choose, by typing a number on that word(the `enumerate(words)` gives a number to the word) and if the player has chosen the correct word he/she will win and the loop, else the player will have to choose again until he/she runs out of chances.(i tried this by having the `remainingGuess -=1`) I used the `True` to make it a boolean. My question is how can I make my loop work because it is currently broken and I don't know what to do. Thank you.

```
import random
Names = ['AETHER', 'BADGED', 'BALDER', 'BANDED', 'BANTER', 'BARBER', 'BASHER'] #ect, etc

def wordlist(words):
    for index, item in enumerate(words):
        print(index, ") ", item, sep='')

available_words = random.sample(Names, 8)
one = random.choice(available_words)

print("Welcome to the Guess-The-Word Game.\nThe Password is one of these words:")
wordlist(available_words)

def Main():
    remainingGuess = 4
    while remainingGuess > 0 and False:
        wordlist(available_words)
        print("Guesses remaining: ", remainingGuess)
        userNum =  int(input("Enter guess number between 0-7: "))
        print(userNum)
        if wordlist[userNum] == one:
            win = True
            print("You are Correct")
            else: 
            print("You  incorrect")
            remainingGuess -=1
    if win == True
        break
```

Comment: The `and false` is preventing true loop from running, as for an and-gate both inputs need to be true.

Comment: Hi Oisin, Sorry for that part, I was not sure what to do at all and came across another post from stack overflow and I tried to use the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `available_words = random.sample(Names, 7)` not `available_words = random.sample(Names, 8)` There are not enough items for 8.
- Change `while remainingGuess > 0 and False:` to `while remainingGuess > 0:` because False will avoid your loop to *loop*.
- After `print(userNum)`

  ```
  if wordlist[userNum] == one:
      win = True
      print("You are Correct")
  else: 
      print("You  incorrect")

  if win == true:
      remainingGuess = 0
  else:
      remainingGuess -=1
  ```

You were decrementing `remainingGuess` only when `wordlist[userNum] == one`. You have to decrement every time you loop. And if you win, to break the loop, set `remainingGuess` to 0.

- You were not calling `Main()`
- Change `wordlist[userNum]` to `available_words[userNum]`
- You were using `win` variable before initializing. Add `win = False` just before while loop.

---

I found out your code was full of errors when I tried to run. Here is the fixed version:

```
import random
Names = ['AETHER', 'BADGED', 'BALDER', 'BANDED', 'BANTER', 'BARBER', 'BASHER'] #ect, etc

def wordlist(words):
    for index, item in enumerate(words):
        print(index, ") ", item, sep='')

available_words = random.sample(Names, 7)
one = random.choice(available_words)

print("Welcome to the Guess-The-Word Game.\nThe Password is one of these words:")
wordlist(available_words)


def Main():
    remainingGuess = 4
    win = False
    while remainingGuess > 0:
        wordlist(available_words)
        print("Guesses remaining: ", remainingGuess)
        userNum =  int(input("Enter guess number between 0-7: "))
        print(userNum)
        if available_words[userNum] == one:
            win = True
            print("You are Correct")
        else: 
            print("You  incorrect")
        if win == True:
            remainingGuess = 0
        else:
            remainingGuess -= 1

Main()
```

Comment: Care to explain what you did in your answer?

Comment: @Oisin Edited my answer, is it clear now?

Comment: yes it's good now.

Comment: Hi Saibot, I read your code and comment, thank you very much it really helps by breaking down each of my problems. The reason I was using `available_words = random.sample(Names, 8)` was because actually my list has more than 8 words but I had to cut it out for the post.(the #etc was meaning I had more words) From your code now I understand properly how to use the True, False and if, else in my loop. Thank you so much! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `and` Statement will only return True if both arguments are. So if you type `and False` it will never run. Just remove this part